# Expand html collapsible lists automatically in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of information from a particular website that contains a list of different species belonging to Mollusca. The main page is http://emollusks.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/8

Once I get to a particular species (e.g. http://emollusks.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/12257), extracting the information itself is not a problem. However, if you navigate to the main page above, you'll realize that it contains a collapse-type menu starting in 'Mollusca'. Thus, to get to a particular species, I have to first expand that menu manually, save the .html page, and only then parse it in R using XML. I'd like to develop a R script that starts at the main page and automatically expands all possible boxes so I can later access information for each species at once. I have no idea where to start though.

Thanks very much for your assistance.

### Here's a potential solution based on the chosen answer below by @hrbrmstr

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

tinyTaxUrl  <-  function(ID) {
    sprintf('http://emollusks.myspecies.info/tinytax/get/%s', ID)
}

termTaxUrl  <-  function(ID) {
    sprintf('http://emollusks.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/%s', ID)
}

extractContent  <-  function(...) {
    content(GET(url = tinyTaxUrl(...), 
                add_headers(Referer = termTaxUrl(...)), 
                set_cookies(has_js = '1')))[[2]]$data
}

readHtmlAndReturnTaxID  <-  function(..., verbose = TRUE) {
    if(verbose) {
        cat(..., '\n')
    }
    # use 'try' to ensure that failed connection won't break it
    pg  <-  try(read_html(extractContent(...)), silent = TRUE)
    while(class(pg)[1] == 'try-error') {
        pg  <-  try(read_html(extractContent(...)), silent = TRUE)
    }
    taxaList  <-  pg %>% html_nodes('li > a')
    data.frame(taxa             =  taxaList %>% html_text(),
               ids              =  basename(taxaList %>% html_attr('href')),
               stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
}


startTaxaID  <-  '8'
eBivalvia    <-  readHtmlAndReturnTaxID(startTaxaID)
eBivalvia2   <-  ldply(eBivalvia$ids, readHtmlAndReturnTaxID)
n            <-  1
while(nrow(eBivalvia2) > 0) {
    cat(n, '\n')
    n           <-  n + 1
    eBivalvia   <-  rbind(eBivalvia, eBivalvia2)
    eBivalvia2  <-  ldply(eBivalvia2$ids, readHtmlAndReturnTaxID)
}

eBivalvia$urls  <-  termTaxUrl(eBivalvia$ids)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Developer Tools and watch for the XHR request when you tick the [+]. You can feed the "Copy as cURL" right to my `curlconverter` package and it'll help you turn it into an `httr` request. Then you'll be able to grab the other species and their URLs from the data element XHR response:

```
library(curlconverter)
library(rvest)

cURL <- "curl 'http://emollusks.myspecies.info/tinytax/get/8' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Cookie: has_js=1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: http://emollusks.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/8' --compressed"

req <- make_req(straighten(cURL))
pg <- read_html(httr::content(req[[1]](), as="parsed")[[2]]$data)

html_nodes(pg, "li > a")

## {xml_nodeset (10)}
##  [1] <a href="/taxonomy/term/12" class="">Conchifera</a>
##  [2] <a href="/taxonomy/term/18" class="">Placophora</a>
##  [3] <a href="/taxonomy/term/9" class="">Bivalvia</a>
##  [4] <a href="/taxonomy/term/10" class="">Caudofoveata</a>
##  [5] <a href="/taxonomy/term/11" class="">Cephalopoda</a>
##  [6] <a href="/taxonomy/term/14" class="">Gastropoda</a>
##  [7] <a href="/taxonomy/term/16" class="">Monoplacophora</a>
##  [8] <a href="/taxonomy/term/19" class="">Polyplacophora</a>
##  [9] <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" class="">Scaphopoda</a>
## [10] <a href="/taxonomy/term/21" class="">Solenogastres</a>
```

Here's a modified version of the `httr` call that `curlconverter` generates:

```
library(httr)

GET(url = "http://emollusks.myspecies.info/tinytax/get/8", 
    add_headers(Referer = "http://emollusks.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/8"), 
    set_cookies(has_js = "1"))
```

It should be possible to (eventually) grok the URL pattern and get whatever you need (you can poke around the Drupal [`tinytax`](https://www.drupal.org/project/tinytax) module docs to get an idea for how it works, too).

Comment: +1 Here's a (far) more knowledgeable person I was hoping would come along.  Are you able to expand all the boxes down to species level with this approach?

Comment: every [+] seems to be an XHR so all one has to do is figure out the URL pattern. I'll add a modified version of the `httr` function that `curlconverter` generates to the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I added on the main thread a script based on your answer that seems to do the trick! It runs very slowly though, and I suspect it does so because there are too many nested collapsible boxes (there are nearly 100,000 species of Mollusca!!). Anyway, if you have the time, please let me know if there are any ways to improve (i.e. speed up) the code.